# Operator which is invariant in terms of left shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $l:l^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a linear map( where $l^{\infty}$ is the set of bounded sequences) such that the following holds:

(i) $l(Tx)=l(x)$, where T is the left shift operator

(ii) if $x=x_n\geq0$, then $l(x)\geq 0$

(iii) $l(e)=1$ with $e=(1,1,1,1,.....)\in l^{\infty}$

And I want to proof the following 2 (of 4, so maybe not all points above are needed now) tasks:

(a) $l\in l^{\infty}(\mathbb R)'$ and $||l||=1$

(b) For $(x_n)_n\in l^{\infty}$ holds: $lim inf_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n\leq l(x)\leq lim sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$

Comment: Got the first by myself (a). So I just need help with (b).

Answer (score 2):

As for (b), let $m = \liminf_n x_n$ and $M= \limsup_n x_n$.

For all $\varepsilon >0$ you have eventually $x_n - m + \varepsilon \geq 0$. Then, shifting enough the sequence, you get that
$$l(x +(-m + \varepsilon)e) \geq 0$$
i.e.
$$l(x) + (-m + \varepsilon) l(e) = l(x) + -m + \varepsilon \geq 0$$

by arbitrarity of $\varepsilon$ you get $l(x) \geq m$.

The other inequality can be proved similarly.

Note that (b) implies (a) since for all $x$ you have
$$-||x||_{\infty}=- \sup_n|x_n| \leq \liminf_n x_n \leq l(x) \leq \limsup_n x_n \leq \sup_n|x_n| \leq ||x||_{\infty}$$

So $|l(x)| \leq ||x||_{\infty}$. Finally, the equality holds for the constant sequence $e$, so the norm of $l$ must be $||l||=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped a lot! One question: What do you mean by "eventually" in line 2? can you be more specific?

Comment: The meaning is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventually_(mathematics) .